# Vehicle Fitment Data Merge Overlapping Years

Tags: sql-server

I have a large data set of vehicle fitment information for products, each on their own row.
I am struggling to create a query to select only the minimum and maximum years for each overlapping entry.
For example, I have data such as:

```
fromyear    toyear  makename    modelname   submodelname    wheelbase   BedLength   BedTypeName bodytype    note1   Note2   note3   partterminologyname exppartno
2008    2012    Chevrolet   Silverado 1500  LT  NULL    78.00   Fleetside   NULL    Black   NULL    NULL    Truck Bed Mat   37807
2010    2010    Chevrolet   Silverado 1500  LT  NULL    78.00   Fleetside   NULL    Black   NULL    NULL    Truck Bed Mat   37807
2014    2017    Chevrolet   Silverado 1500  LT  NULL    78.00   Fleetside   NULL    Black   NULL    NULL    Truck Bed Mat   37807
```

I am not concerned with keeping the data, so I've moved my focus to an UPDATE query by selecting the minimum and maximum years, but adding something like

```
(SELECT MIN(p2.fromyear)
FROM prod AS p2
WHERE p1.fromyear > 0
AND p2.toyear >= p1.fromyear
AND p2.fromyear < p1.fromyear
AND ISNULL(p2.makename, '') = ISNULL(p1.makename, '')
AND ISNULL(p2.modelname, '') = ISNULL(p1.modelname, '')
AND ISNULL(p2.submodelname, '') = ISNULL(p1.submodelname, '')
AND ISNULL(FLOOR(p2.wheelbase), 0) = ISNULL(FLOOR(p1.wheelbase), 0)
AND ISNULL(FLOOR(p2.BedLength), 0) = ISNULL(FLOOR(p1.BedLength), 0)
AND ISNULL(p2.BedTypeName, '') = ISNULL(p1.BedTypeName, '')
AND ISNULL(p2.bodytype, '') = ISNULL(p1.bodytype, '')
AND ISNULL(p2.note1, '') = ISNULL(p1.note1, '')
AND ISNULL(p2.Note2, '') = ISNULL(p1.Note2, '')
AND ISNULL(p2.note3, '') = ISNULL(p1.note3, '')
AND ISNULL(p2.exppartno, '') = ISNULL(p1.exppartno, '')) AS newfrom
```

causes the query to run for an excessive amount of time (pulling from a table with over 150k rows).
After doing an UPDATE to merge the years, I can simply remove any duplicate rows.

The desired result would return only two rows for this model, 2008-2012 and 2014-2017

My original idea was to simply select MIN(fromyear) and MAX(toyear), however this leaves me with an issue of having the invalid year of 2013 as an option.

Is there some simple way to formulate a query to handle overlapping years like this? Everything I found in my searches did not involve matching multiple columns of data.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could also show us what the table looks like after the update (select?).  It is not clear what you actually want to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest joining onto a date table, with a list of sequential years as follows (to cover the full range of years in the source data):

```
year
-----
...
2008
2009
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
...
```

So joining your source table to the date table `ON (year >= fromyear AND year <= toyear)`, gives the following results:

```
year   fromyear    toyear  vehicle_descriptor

2008   2008        2012    Chevrolet...
2009   2008        2012    Chevrolet...
2010   2008        2012    Chevrolet...
2011   2008        2012    Chevrolet...
2012   2008        2012    Chevrolet...

2010   2010        2010    Chevrolet...

2014   2014        2017    Chevrolet...
2015   2014        2017    Chevrolet...
2016   2014        2017    Chevrolet...
2017   2014        2017    Chevrolet...
```

Then group (or select distinct) the rows to eliminate duplicate years. (I'm using "vehicle_descriptor" as a shorthand for all the columns that uniquely identify a vehicle in your source data.)

On the deduplicated results, add a column as follows:

```
(year - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vehicle_descriptor ORDER BY year ASC) ) AS year_group
```

This produces a unique number for every year *or continuous sequence of years*.

```
year   fromyear    toyear  veicle_descriptor  row_number                  year_group (year - row_number)

2008   2008        2012    Chevrolet...       1                           2007
2009   2008        2012    Chevrolet...       2                           2007
2010   2008        2012    Chevrolet...       3                           2007
2011   2008        2012    Chevrolet...       4                           2007
2012   2008        2012    Chevrolet...       5                           2007

2010   2010        2010    Chevrolet...       (this row removed as year 2010 is a duplicate)

2014   2014        2017    Chevrolet...       6                           2008
2015   2014        2017    Chevrolet...       7                           2008
2016   2014        2017    Chevrolet...       8                           2008
2017   2014        2017    Chevrolet...       9                           2008
```

Finally, once you have this year_group, simply group the rows in the way you originally envisaged, by vehicle_descriptor and year_group, and select the MIN(year) and MAX(year).

The year_group value has no particular significance is not retained in the final results - it's just there to differentiate the sequences. It works because it increments every time there is a discontinuity in the year sequence (and it increments by the amount of discontinuity).

I hope I've explained that satisfactorily. I'm not at my desktop PC, so I've written it all out by hand! If there's anything unclear, or you need a code example, let me know and I'll come back to you.

Comment: Steve, this was very useful information and a great idea to split the years and remove duplicates! One trick that I had no idea about was the use of OVER with PARTITION BY. This idea to take year - ROW_NUMBER was an elegant solution to help in grouping with the gaps in year ranges! This with a combination of 3 chained CTE's provided the complete solution to my problem.